# How do I assert a `number` type is positive?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have the following function for finding the square root of a number:

```
function sqrt(n: number): number {
    return Math.sqrt(n);
}
```

I would like to find a way to assert that the given number is non-negative.  Currently, the `Math.sqrt` function returns `NaN` for negative numbers which can introduce sneaky bugs so I'd rather catch these simply errors at compile-time.  Is there any  way to make TypeScript error when the given `number` is not positive?

Answer (score 10):

You can do this via some string intrinsics and conditional types.  Basically, we can take in a generic for the number, `N`.  Then, stringify that number type via `${N}` and check if that string begins with a `-` meaning that the number is in fact negative.  If so, we can return `never` to force TypeScript to fail on the generic argument.

```
type AssertPositive<N extends number> =
  number extends N ? N : `${N}` extends `-${string}` ? never : N;

function sqrt<N extends number>(n: AssertPositive<N>): number {
    return Math.sqrt(n);
}

// No Errors 
sqrt(5);
sqrt(0);
sqrt(1.5);
sqrt(1e3);

// Correctly errors 
sqrt(-5);
sqrt(-1);
sqrt(-3.4);
sqrt(-0.4);
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggznCAnYAFA9nAlsLA3CAHgDkoIAPYCAOwBM4pqBXAWwCNkA+KAXkdY5IylGvSikA-OKgAuKAAMAJAG9iAX3nCqdBvIC0KuMCRZqAcw1Qp1CASFziAbgCwAKDcAzJtQDGudNRQcACOKCRaogzM7FwAFNRy8IgoGNi4BCScAJRy0YJQym5QxVBIEMBMSIEAsgCGwAAWAHQhKPFZLq5qbm4A9L3i6FAAokhI6EgMgDwbgJH7bq3AsQCsHfOhiwAMq64LsQCMTSudu3sQAMzbfQMAwhNlfgA2IGRjE9NzO+uxekdrbXp7ba7PRnJoAFiBXz0G3B2yAA)

The `number extends N ? N` clause of `AssertPositive` was simply to make `AssertPositive` allow non-exact numeric types (`number`) to work with `sqrt` because there is no way to make sure the `number` type is positive / negative as it provides no context.

### Force Cast for `number` type (credits @jcalz)

As [@jcalz mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71670965/how-do-i-assert-a-number-type-is-positive/71670966#comment126683512_71670966), you may want to force an explicit cast when providing a `number` type to `sqrt`.  This can be done via branded types which basically attach some context to the `number` type itself.  [Here is the playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NDPq4N) that @jcalz created to showcase this behavior.

Comment: What even is this language that `-${string}` is a valid type? That's next-level stuff.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo that's just a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) and they are very handy for enforcing patterns in strings.

Comment: You do say this but maybe it should be made more clear, that this only works with numeric [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), and that `sqrt(0 - 5)` cannot be adequately checked because the compiler doesn't do math at the type level.  Personally if I wanted to rely on the compiler to do this I'd probably make it *reject* `number` and force you to call `sqrt((0-5) as NonNegative)` for some `NonNegative` (maybe a branded primitive) so that you are at least making the user go through the exercise of considering what they're doing.

Comment: Like [this Playground example](https://tsplay.dev/NDPq4N) maybe

Comment: Yeah I agree @jcalz I've update the answer to describe your example as well.